# Легкие задачки на С.В чем проблема?

Tags: c++, c, массивы, сортировка

Сами три маленькие задачки представлены на png-гэшке.Хотелось бы узнать, куда пропадают значения после запятой при сортировке..И почему неверно считается произведение..Буду очень благодарна за помощь!
Тест программы размещен под кодом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
void bubbleSort(float *num, int size)
{
 
  int i , j;
  for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
  {
    for (j = (size - 1); j > i; j--) 
    {
      if (num[j - 1] > num[j]) 
      {
        int temp = num[j - 1]; 
        num[j - 1] = num[j];
        num[j] = temp;
      }
    }
  }
}


int main() {
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    float A[N];
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            scanf ("%f",&A[i]);

        }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (A[i] > 0) {
            sum += A[i];
        }
    }
float MAX=0, MIN = pow(10,10);    
int i1, n2;
     for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (abs(A[i]) > MAX) {
            MAX=abs(A[i]);
            i1=i;
        }
        if (abs(A[i]) < MIN) {
            MIN=abs(A[i]);
            n2=i;
        }
    }
float pr = 1;
if (i1<n2 ){
    for (i = i1; i <= n2; i++) {
        pr=pr* A[i];
    }
} 
else{
    for (i = n2; i <= i1; i++) {
        pr=pr* A[i];
    }
    
} 
    printf("%.4f\n", sum);
    printf("%.4f\n", pr);
    bubbleSort(A, N);
    //InsertionSort(N,A);
     for ( i = N-1; i>=0; i--)
    printf("%.4f ", A[i]);
 
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `int temp = num[j - 1];`

Comment: @user7860670 точно..!Спасибо :) Но что по поводу произведения?

Comment: Что-то проблема с произведением [не воспроизводится](https://ideone.com/hnNS2m). А ничего ли вы от нас не утаили?

Comment: @wololo я вставил код по вашей ссылке в свой компилятор - ответ 15.1800 во второй строке, всё так же..Но там  у вас 10.1200..Я не понимаю..

Comment: @wololo просто во втором же тесте, где 2 числа - ситуация аналогичная.Что такие числа стоят рядом.Но почему то мой тест с двумя числами проходит как нужно, но вот с первым тестовым примером..не выходит почему то..в чем дело?

Comment: Похоже вы компилируете программу компилятором языка Си. Замените все `abs` на `fabs`

Comment: @wololo Да..дело было именно в этом!Теперь ответ верный выводится.Спасибо!!